# Is there a way to automatically play music when headphones are plugged in? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, audio, playback

Is there any way to configure the audio driver (on windows 10) in a way that it will automatically start playing music when it detects that headphones have been plugged in to the audio jack?

Answer (score 0):

In general, no this will not work. It may be that some particular machine might, but on the machines here, plugging in headphones diverts the sound but does not kick off any process.

Comment: There must be something that runs because a Realtek Audio window pops up every time i plug anything into the jack.

Comment: I tried that and nothing popped up so in general I do not see a way.  One machine here is Realtek, the other is Conexant.